# PHP MySQL Multiple Insertion

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong :(

```
if(isset($_POST['finish'])){
$objectives=addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['item']));

    foreach ($objectives AS $objective) {
        echo "$objective <br />";
    }

}
```

It's not showing anything.. what have I missed out? I'm trying to get data from multiple input entries..

```
<input class="item" id="objectives" name="item[]" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: well, the first thing you missed is the type of your input...

Comment: `addslashes` and `strip_tags` work on string literals, not arrays. `error_reporting(E_ALL)` would have told you that immediately.

Comment: `$_POST['item']` is an array

Comment: What is the input type?

Comment: what is the value of $_POST['finish'] ? Is the block even getting run

Comment: @Bartdude Note: The default type is: text. see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: @ebyrob > thanks for that, although I don't rely on W3schools much, I didn't know that. I'm not a big fan of default values though :-)

Comment: @Bartdude If you like the spec better: "The missing value default is the Text state." see: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/forms.html#the-input-element  (so it shouldn't be browser dependent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if you have multiple `<input class="item" id="objectives" name="item[]" />` then `$_POST['item']` will be an array and not a string. So you have to iterate over it or apply an  [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function.

```
$items = array_map('strip_tags',$items);
$items = array_map('addslashes',$items);
```

Your code would then be

```
if(isset($_POST['finish'])){
    $_POST['item'] = array_map('strip_tags',$_POST['item']);
    $_POST['item'] = array_map('addslashes',$_POST['item']);

    foreach ($_POST['item'] AS $objective) {
        echo "$objective <br />";
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, how do i go about doing that properly?

Comment: Haha, def need to keep practicing this...

This most likely won't work.. well... it doesn't haha but I'm not getting any errors in my log...

     if(isset($_POST['finish'])){
 $items=addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['item']));

 $items = array_map('strip_tags',$items);
 $items = array_map('addslashes',$items);

 echo $items;

}

Comment: You need to remove `$items=addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['item'])); ` Also `$items` is intended to represent `$_POST['item']`.

Comment: Ok, starting to make sense, could you possible struture it to actually work for me... because i removed it.. it doesn't even echo anything out.. feel like a dumb ass at the moment, but yeah, it happens.. thanks nick!

Comment: Brilliant Nick! Now it all makes sense... I've never had to use an array_map so this has been a slight learning curve.. THANKS AGAIN! MASSIVE HELP!

Comment: One more thing..sorry, can i insert each value into the database using a mysql query within the foreach loop? 

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO objectives (id,objective) VALUES (,$objective)");`

Comment: yes except you will want to omit the `id` column if it is auto incrementing, use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) on any user input variable you send to the database. and upgrade to use mysqli_* functions and the mysql_* extension is deprecated.

Comment: Yes thanks.. I don't think the current version of MAMP That i'm using supports mysqli.. Also, i have a working connection to my database, but it doesn't insert.. i've double checked everything matches up.. this is a night mare.. Most likely fustrating you swell..

`if(isset($_POST['finish'])){
    $_POST['item'] = array_map('strip_tags',$_POST['item']);
    $_POST['item'] = array_map('addslashes',$_POST['item']);

    foreach ($_POST['item'] AS $objective) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO objectives (objective) VALUES ($objective)");
     
    }

}`

This does nothing.. but it echo's

Comment: `"INSERT INTO objectives (objective) VALUES ('$objective')"` Need quotes around a string you are inserting.

Comment: Lol now i feel like a lemon.. I missed them out by accident.. attention to detail aye, thanks again for the final time :)

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is that any tag that has brackets([]) is put in the superglobal array as an array. You will need to loop over your this or use array_map to perform functions on this array.

My extended answer is that if you are using php 5.2 or later you can use the filter_var_array to perform this operation without iterating over your array in php. As well as do type checking. filter_var and filter_var_array have to many filter options for me to cover. Please see the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php

```
if(isset($_POST['finish'])) {
    $objectives = filter_var_array($_POST['item'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

foreach ($objectives AS $objective) {
    echo "$objective <br />";
}
```

}